# upload text file to heroku

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, heroku

How do I upload a text file to a website hosted on heroku?

I know this question has been asked in various forms but I am looking for a specific situation so I apologize for all the code spam below.

So I have a website I have been playing with on cloud 9 ( Im new to web development as will soon become apparent ). There I have a program that runs kruskels algorithm on some input to find a minimum spanning tree. I have written this program in java back when I was in school and I have incorporated it into my Node.js driven website.

The java program takes "input.txt", does its thing, and outputs to "output.txt". It worked fine on c9. I could upload a file with the code I will link below, capture(?) it in my HTML, POST it to the same page. this worked by overwriting the current text files. And I believe this is the sticking point for heroku.

when I deployed to Heroku this obviously did not work. When I was reading questions on stack overflow or general solutions to this I found that due to the ephemeral file system the text file will revert back to its original upon reset. I thought this would be OK due to the fact I only needed the files long enough to input/output them from my java program. However, I found that while the input.txt would indeed be updated as desired, as soon as I res.redirected that input back to the same page it would disappear and revert back.

reading online suggested using S3...which I started doing until they asked for a credit card without the ability to cap my data..and as a newbie developer I refuse to risks 1000s upon 1000s of dollars to a mistake I will likely make.

I have now downloaded cloudinary. but I feel like most of the things I read only have part of the puzzle, as it seems to focus primarily on images. Im lost and I have to believe this is an insanely common scenario that Im just overlooking or have been unlucky enough to find the wrong info upon google searches. How would someone suggest to do this very simple scenario where I need to update text files. I will link the code I have below.

here is my html:

```
<form ref="uploadForm" id="uploadForm" action="/kruskelPost" method="post" encType="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" name="myFile" />
<input type='submit' value="Upload!"/></form>
```

I am new to posting code sorry if this is incorrect. im copying this one line at a time i guess...

here is my node.js on app.js ( what it used to look like when it worked on c9 ):

```
app.post("/kruskelPost", function(req, res) {

if (!req.files) return res.status(400).send('No files were uploaded.');

locals.input = true; // jsut booleans to manage what is shown when...not too important.

req.files.myFile.mv( "src/input.txt", function(err) {

 if (err) return res.status(500).send(err);
locals.ups = false; // this is just to let /kruskel page know not to display a outputfile (until I run the program, because this would display the old output.txt)
});
res.redirect("/kruskel");
});
```

this is how it was displayed back on the original page in html:

```
<span style="white-space:pre"><% if (locals.input == true) { %><% include ./../src/input.txt %><% }  %></span>
```

this is what I was trying to do with cloudinary:

```
    app.post("/kruskelPost", function(req, res) {

    cloudinary.v2.uploader.upload(req.files.myFile.name, 
    { resource_type: "auto" }, 
    function(error, result) {console.log(result); });
```

as is apparent I dont know how to handle the first parameter. I dont even know how to name the file or how to point to the file that was recently uploaded...anyway. Im clearly lost and ALL I need is this last big worked out and its driving me nuts. any help as to how to handle this situation would be greatly appreciated. I can link my heroku page but im not sure if im allowed to ( if it makes it easier to see it).

Answer (score 0):

You have a very specific case, but i will try to answer the best way i can.

i suggest you to add a database(postgress,free) to your heroku app. Then save the text in the database instead of a text file. and work with it from there.

The way heroku works, specially if you are using it free, it will reset all the file in your server every time the dynos restart. thats why you are not supposet to store dynamic files in heroku.

Update: Here is how to provision a postgres database to heroku-nodejs
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgresql#connecting-in-node-js

Comment: Thanks you kindly. before I read this comment I was messing with the mongoDB database, ( which im guessing is kinda the same thing? just a different company?). Im still new to it but I guess my main concern was how to do line processing within my java program. each line of the text file has 3 numbers.. 2 ints and a float. will I be making a call to my database every line to receive the data of a file... or will I be doing the same when Im writing the info to a database...can I even do that from inside a java file....can I write to database from inside a java file I mean?....

Comment: well either way Im watching some tutorials now on how best to work with databases. looks like there is no easy one line solution...I just have to familiarize myself with databases first. thank you for the comment. I voted it up but apparently Im new so it doesnt show yet :(

Comment: Actually, analizing your problem better, if you are making a web app i think you should just show an input text on the site to enter the text or a upload button, the 2nd would be more complicated but necesary if you want to work with a large file.

Answer (score 0):

The Heroku filesystem isn't just ephemeral, it's immutable, which means you can't write *anything* to the filesystem. If all you need though are the processed results, you can upload the file, read it, and then respond with the processed results. That wouldn't require you to store the file anywhere. And if you don't really need the file to stay changed anywhere, this is a better solution.

Comment: the way I got around it was a little crazy. and I know there are better ways but I just kinda needed it done overnight. I saved the txt file to a string upon uploading...because a string will not disappear or revert ( also I could use that string to send back to the original page ). then when I called my function to run I did all the following within the same scope of myfunction:

1) made a new txt file with the string I made earlier
2) ran the function ( which used the txt file as input and output to another txt file
3) then I wrote THAT output txt file to a string as well

Ill post

Answer (score 0):

```
app.post("/kruskelPost", function(req, res) {

inputString   = req.files.myFile.data.toString();
locals.inputStringData = inputString;

res.redirect("/kruskel");
});
```

// this is when I actually post the info

```
var locals     = { ups: false, input:false, nodes: [], inputStringData: "nothing uploaded yet", outputStringData: "nothing uploaded yet"};
```

// just my local variables that I can send between routing pages

// and then this absurdly long workaround

```
 function myFunc() {


     var stream = fs.createWriteStream("./src/input.txt");

    stream.once('open', function(fd) {
         stream.write( locals.inputStringData );
         stream.end();
    });

    // now to actually run the java program
    child = exec('java -cp src Proj3',
      function (error, stdout, stderr) {

          console.log("kruskel algorithm run");
        // console.log('stdout: ' + stdout);
        // console.log('stderr: ' + stderr);
        if (error !== null) {
          console.log('exec error: ' + error);
        }

       locals.outputStringData = "";

        //workaround printing output to a string variable so it survives the ephemeral file system of heroku
        var fileName = "./src/output.ejs";

        fs.exists(fileName, function(exists) {
          if (exists) {
            fs.stat(fileName, function(error, stats) {
              fs.open(fileName, "r", function(error, fd) {
                var buffer = new Buffer(stats.size);

                fs.read(fd, buffer, 0, buffer.length, null, function(error, bytesRead, buffer) {
                 locals.outputStringData = buffer.toString("utf8", 0, buffer.length);

                  fs.close(fd);
                });
              });
            });
          }
        }); 
    });

}
```

// just to see, heres what happens when someone pushes the button to run it

```
app.get("/kruskelRun", function(req, res) {
myFunc();
locals.ups = true;
setTimeout(function (){

    res.redirect("kruskel");
}, 1000);

});
```

Comment: man Im really going to have to get used to posting code... apparently IM awful at it